# How to collect flows from two different room tables and combine the data to show in recyclerview in android

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am not an expert in coroutine flows so really need help with the same.
I have two room databases in android i.e. UserData and UserProfileImage.

```
data class UserData(
val UserName : String,
val MobileNumber : String,
val tags : List<String>)
```

```
data class UserProfileImage(
val MobileNumber : String,
val ProfileUrl : String)
```

i have created two queries to fetch flow from both the tables like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users_profile")
fun getUserProfileList() : Flow<List<UserProfileImage>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM users_data")
fun getUserDataList() : Flow<List<UserData>>
```

my end goal is to collect data from both the tables and combine them like CombinedData(val UserName : String, val MobileNumber : String, val tags : List, val ProfileUrl : String) based on the "MobileNumber" value and finally show them in recyclerview.
how can i combine the collect functions so that if any one of those table observes any changes in the data then the combined data should also gets updated ultimately resulting in my recyclerview getting updated.
Thanks in advance.

i have read about flatMapMerge, flatMapConcat etc but can't fully understand how exactly i can use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating two flows and merging them later, You can create a single flow with the help of ROOMDB relations.

```
data class UserDataWithProfile(
    @Embedded val userData: UserData,
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "MobileNumber",
         entityColumn = "MobileNumber"
    )
    val profileImage: UserProfileImage
)
```

And when you want to query from ROOMDB, you can query the flow of UserData with Profile Image using single query -

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM users_data")
fun getUserDataProfileList(): Flow<UserDataWithProfile>
```

Comment: in this case, if my background server API updates the "users_profile" table with the latest user images, will the flow automatically collect the new data so that I can update those images in recyclerview?

Comment: Yes, in a one-to-one relationship between two tables in Room DB, any change in either table will trigger a flow that gets the related data.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to get rid of the two tables at the first place. If your users have only one image each, then you can store link to the image in the user table.
If it is not the case, you can use SQL JOIN statement to join the tables. In this case your Room function would be

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM UserData JOIN UserProfileImage ON UserData.MobileNumber = UserProfileImage.MobileNumber")
fun getUsersWithImages(): Flow<Map<UserData,List<UserProfileImage>>>
```

This should do exactly what you want without explicitly combinig `Flow`s.

However, if you still looking for doing in not in Room layer, it can be done as follows:

```kotlin
val usersFlow = getUserDataList()
val picturesFlow = getUserProfileList()
val mergedFlow: Flow<Map<UserData, List<UserProfileImage>>> = usersFlow.combine(picturesFlow) { users, profiles ->
   val usersProfiles = profiles.groupBy { it.MobileNumber }
   val result = buildMap {
     for (user in users) {
       put(user,usersProfiles[user.MobileNumber])
     }
   }
   result
}
```